# Am I understanding the Virtual Dom correctly?

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

I'm working on a basic introduction to React program and was wondering if I am understanding the diffing of the virtual dom correctly.

I have this small app:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const svgStyle = {
  border: '1px solid black'
};

const Circle =({x, y}) => (
  <circle cx={x} cy={y} r="5" />
);

class Canvas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      circles: []
    };

    this.addCircle = this.addCircle.bind(this);
  }

  addCircle(e) {

    const {left: rectLeft, top: rectTop} = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const {clientX, clientY} = e;

    this.setState({
      circles: this.state.circles.concat([{x: clientX - rectLeft, y: clientY - rectTop}])
    });
  }

  render() {
    var {circles} = this.state;

    return (
      <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" onClick={this.addCircle} style={svgStyle}>
        {
          circles.map(circle => (<Circle x={circle.x} y={circle.y} r="5" />))
        }
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default Canvas;
```

My question is, do all the svg `<circles>` get re-rendered whenever I add one to the state object? Or does React diff the fact that the ones in the state were already there and doesn't need to do anything with them.

Comment: This may help: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html . React only rerenders what changed.

Answer (score 0):

All the `<circle>` tags get re-rendered whenever you add one more or update the state.

When rendering a collection (`.map`), React recommends the use of a `key` property with a value that uniquely identifies the instance being rendered.

So to implement this I would suggest adding an id property to the circle object and then render it as:

```
circles.map(circle => 
    <Circle key={circle.id} x={circle.x} y={circle.y} r="5" />
)
```

So next time that React makes a diff it knows to compare the `<Circle key="1" ... />` with the `<Circle key="1" ... />` in the shadow DOM, and only update the DOM if it has changed.